# Working with leaflets

Tags: lists, fancybox, leaflet

i am making a menu, and i've stumble on a formatting issue. The way it works now is that

> "Name (empty space) price"

I would like it to be

> "Name.......Price"

still taking up the same width as now.

Anyone have a solution?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{leaflet}
\usepackage[top=1.5in, bottom=1.5in, left=1.4in, right=1.4in]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}% for better rules in the table

\begin{document}
\ovalbox{
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {Xr}
Pasta Bolognaise & 69,- \\
Paste Carbonara & 69,-
\end{tabu}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If the currency is €, then 69,- is a little steep for pasta ;).

Comment: its Kr. :D thats 1€ / 7,5 kr. :-)

Comment: I have tried to make an exstra column and used \dotfill , but now there is a gap between the dots and (maybe column spacing or padding) anyone know how change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fill the first column with dots after the content use the `tabu`-preamble

```
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {X<{\dotfill}@{}r}
```

## MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{leaflet}
\usepackage[top=1.5in, bottom=1.5in, left=1.4in, right=1.4in]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}% for better rules in the table

\begin{document}
\ovalbox{
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {X<{\dotfill}@{}r}
Pasta Bolognaise & 69,- \\
Paste Carbonara & 69,-
\end{tabu}
}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{leaflet}
\usepackage[top=1.5in, bottom=1.5in, left=1.4in, right=1.4in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancybox,pict2e}

\begin{document}
\ovalbox{%
  \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
    Pasta \dotfill Bolognaise  69,00 \\
    Paste \dotfill Carbonara   69,50}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]